# what does" I think this is a very cruel, inhumane, unethical and illegal practice" mean?

Tags: meaning

I don't understand the word "practice" here, my guess is it equals "action" but I'm not certain of it.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/practice

Comment: As Andrew linked,  Sense 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Practice generally refers to an ongoing or repeated behavior. Eating a dog, for example, would be seen by most as a cruel *act* if done once. It would be a cruel *practice* if done repeatedly.